# How are Japanese Maple Trees cultivated?

Tags: trees, tree-care, japanese-maple, maple

I have mature Japanese maple trees in my yard that are extremely fertile. I find dozens, if not hundreds of saplings all over the yard. Some have even grown several feet tall. Is there a way I can properly cultivate these saplings so that I can give them away and maybe even sell them?

Comment: I wish they would self-seed in the UK! I'm sure you would have no difficulty selling them here, where they are pretty expensive..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following page has some information on Japanese Maple seedlings and saplings, although it is mainly about seed,grafting, and cuttings:

http://www.soonerplantfarm.com/index.cfm/fuseaction/specials.specDetail/recID/16

We have a similar problem with elms. Although I've left a volunteer to grow, I usually let the lawn mower get the rest, and physically pull them out of plant pots.