# How can I grow maple trees from seeds?

Tags: trees, seeds, seed-starting, propagation, maple

I have a mature maple tree in my yard. Every year it drops seeds which start growing in the most inconvenient of places, like my gutters. Next season I would like to actively cultivate these seeds and plant some new maple trees where I want them.

What will I need to plan for to make this project successful?

Is growing trees from seeds as simple as growing anything else from seeds?

Comment: http://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/176/cultivating-japanese-maple-trees

Comment: Is a Japanese Maple radically different from a regular maple?

Comment: See the "stratified" link in my answer for the differences between types of maples.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Start by making sure your seed are "[stratified](http://forums2.gardenweb.com/forums/load/seed/msg0520414323484.html?28)" (put through a cold period to simulate winter).

An example of stratification: usually started mid-February.

> Essentially, you break the wings off the seeds, put them in a jar of
>   warm water, and let them soak for a day, then you put them in some
>   damp peat moss, sand, soil, etc in a plastic bag (with a few holes
>   poked in it) and store the bag in your refrigerator for 90 days or
>   until the seeds begin to sprout.
>   - [link](http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=212625)

Then around mid-May (or sooner if they sprout in the fridge) plant them in a pot.

The temperature and duration of Stratification depends on the climate your seeds like. See the link "Stratified" for more information on various trees' stratification requirements.

Comment: Or just replant the ones growing in the gutter :)

Comment: Could you just section off a certain rectangle of garden space and space them evenly over grass? That would leave the environment just the same as the rest of the yard, give a place to winter them (because they would normally there). Assuming OP doesn't want them as potted plants.